# Merge multiple tables having different columns

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 4 tables each tables has different number of columns as listed below.

```
tableA - 34
tableB - 47
tableC - 26
tableD - 16
```

Every table has a common column called id, now i need to perform a union the problem is since the columns are not equal length and entirely different i can't do a union.

Based on id only i can get the details from every table, so how should i approach this.

What is the optimized way to solve this, tried full join but that takes too much time.

Tried so far

```
SELECT * FROM tableA FULL JOIN 
              tableB FULL JOIN 
              tableC FULL JOIN 
              tableD 
         USING (id)
         WHERE tableA.id = 123 OR
               tableB.id = 123 OR
               tableC.id = 123 OR
               tableD.id = 123
```

Comment: Snowflake and Postgres are two very different database products. Which one do you really use?

Comment: You can always do a union by filling the missing columns with NULL values, e.g. `select id, c1, c2, c3, c4 from t1 union all select id, null, col_1, null, col_2 from t2`. The widest table will define the number (and types) of columns. Another option - at least in Postgres - might be to turn every row into a single JSON value. Whether that is a viable solution depends on what you want to do with the data

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake does have a [declared limitation in use of Set operators](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/operators-query.html#general-usage-notes) (such as `UNION`):

> When using these operators:
>
> - Make sure that each query selects the same number of columns.
>
> [...]

However, since the column names are well known, it is possible to come up with a superset of all unique column names required in the final result and project them explicitly from each query.

There's not enough information in the question on how many columns overlap (47 unique columns?), or if they are all different (46 + 33 + 25 + 15 = 119 unique columns?). The answer to this would determine the amount of effort required to write out each query, as it would involve adapting a query from the following form:

`SELECT * FROM t1`

Into an explicit form with dummy columns defined with acceptable defaults that match the data type on tables where they are present:

```sql
SELECT
  present_col1,
  NULL AS absent_col2,
  0.0 AS absent_col3,
  present_col4,
  [...]
FROM
  t1
```

You can also use some [meta programming with stored procedures](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-procedure.html) to "generate" such an altered query by inspecting independent result's column names using the [`Statement::getColumnCount()`, `Statement::getColumnName()`, etc. APIs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#object-statement) and forming a superset union version with default/empty values.